# How to hide a content placeholder if it has no children without client code (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I have a ContentPlaceholder inside of a MasterPageView. All of my other pages come from the same master and I have one page that needs about 70% of the behavior in this master. There is a navigation panel in the master that is spitting out un-necessary html even if left blank by the page. Looks like this:

```
<div class="span3">
    <div class="side_navigation">
        <ul>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SideNavigation" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><%-- /master sub-navigation --%>
```

I simply want to hide ALL of this markup whenever my placeholder (SideNavigation) has 0 children. I don't want to use javascript. I'd rather do this work on the server and deliver it to the client with less responsibility and markup. I've already tried doing "this.SideNavigation.Controls.Count" but it always ends up being 0. If there was a way I could tie into a loaded event and then test this logic that would be great. I am ok with making a code-behind file for my master, but it would be nice to be able to accomplish my goal in the .master file only.

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably recommend using a different master page for the page without the navigation.  You can have nested master pages so you don't necessarily need to duplicate code to do this.
However if you do wish to keep it like this, I would personally use a bit of javascript (with jquery) as follows

```
$(function(){
  if($('.span3 .side_navigation ul li').length() == 0){
    $('.span3').hide(); 
  }
});
```

obviously i'd give span3 an ID to make it not hide every span3 but you hopefully get the idea.

Comment: I have already fixed my original issue by simply using a different master page. I still need to know, for my sake, if it is at all possible to not render parts of my html based on whether or not this placeholder was used by the page. Your approach works but the extra markup was processed by the server and spit out on the client which means a slightly longer load time (it shouldn't be anything noticeable... i'm just being technical). Also, the client then has to execute an extra script to locate the element in question and hide it. If a client were slow enough this may produce a "flicker".

Comment: In ASP.NET it was very easy to access a placeholder and check it's children array to see if it is empty. Then I could hide elements or controls based on that data. It was extremely useful for making a fluid layout that could potentially change based on the data it receives. I wonder if MVC can do something similar?